# Better plugin for Julia autocomplete for Vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am new to Julia and wanted to shift from Juno IDE to vs code. Juno has a pretty awesome auto-complete which shows which package a function comes from. I was wondering if there is an external plugin that I could install to get something similar to vs code. The vs code hovering to get the details of the function is good, but I definitely prefer the one Juno offers.

Here is a pic of the Juno autocomplete

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one official Julia VS Code Extension at the moment which does support autocompletion: https://www.julia-vscode.org

The different results you see is just a factor of what the various IDE's are searching for when they populate that autocomplete list.

[image: Image showing autocomplete in VS Code]

Note that this is on the radar of the Julia VS Code team: https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/1199